# How to measures the speed of a context switch on a UNIX/Linux system using Java program

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to measure thread context switching I write below program is that correct way please let me know and wanted to get update on this post.
Any one can help.

/**
Below is the program which I am trying is this a correct way.
*/

```
public class JavaContextSwitch {
    final static Object ob = new Object();
    final static int numberOFThread=10;
    final static MyThread []threadArray =new MyThread[numberOFThread];
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

        long mainThreadStart=System.nanoTime();

        for(int i=0;i<numberOFThread;i++){
            threadArray[i]= new JavaContextSwitch.MyThread(numberOFThread);
            threadArray[i].setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            threadArray[i].start();
            threadArray[i].join();
        }
        System.out.println("All Thread is relaase for job and witing ..");
        //Thread.currentThread().join();

        System.out.println("Waiting is over ");
        long endOfMainThread= System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Total time taken is "+(endOfMainThread-mainThreadStart));
        long sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<numberOFThread;i++){
            long timeTaken=  threadArray[i].timefinish-threadArray[i].startTime;
            System.out.println("Each thread running time "+timeTaken);
            sum=sum+timeTaken;
        }
        System.out.println("Total time taken by thread is "+sum);
        System.out.println("Average "+numberOFThread+" Taken "+(sum/numberOFThread)+" Time ");
        long timeForContextSwitch= (endOfMainThread-mainThreadStart)-sum;
        System.out.println(" Context switch time is "+timeForContextSwitch);
        System.out.println(" Average Context witching "+ (timeForContextSwitch/numberOFThread+1));
    }

    private static class MyThread extends Thread {
        public long startTime;
        public long timefinish;
        int cycle = 0;

        public MyThread(int cycle) {
            this.cycle = cycle;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(" Child thread started"+this.getId());
            startTime=System.nanoTime();
            // Child thread is busy to complete their job.
                for (int i = 0; i < cycle; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 640 * 81; j++)
                    timefinish = System.nanoTime();
            }
                System.out.println("I am done now "+this.getId());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think anything Java would be relevant; it is up to the OS to decide what to run and when, and "what" may be one of your threads or any other process on the running system.

Comment: If you want to measure context-switch times, write a program that, (mostly) only does context-switches.  Two threads looping, swapping a unit around on two semaphores would do it.  Have the threads loop, say, 50000000 times.  Run it on a not-busy system.  Time it with a stopwatch.  Divide the time by 50000000.

Comment: I am seeing for some more help, I will be glad if any one one can suggest or give example in java, if above program is not correct way to get those context switching timings.

Comment: LaxmanG - The correct way to measure context switches is NOT to use Java.  Got it?  Write your tests in C or C++.

Comment: I dont know much C and C++ I need to write in Java. Hope you can understand my problem

Comment: _I need to write in Java._  Yeah, but "context switch" is not part of the Java language, nor is it something you will find in the JVM spec.  It's hard to measure something that you can not control.

Comment: Your "Total Time Taken" includes the time needed for the main thread to _create_ ten new threads.  Creating threads is expensive, *much* more expensive than a mere context switch.

Comment: The output of the above program, can we assume It is approx correct time of context switching ?
Any suggestion @jameslarge?

Comment: I removed my previous comment because I previously failed to notice that the ten threads run sequentially.  No.  This program does not measure context switch time.  It measures (approximately) the time to create and destroy ten threads plus the time to call `System.out.println(...)` twenty two times.

Comment: Probably the closest you could come to measuring context switch time would be to write a program with _two_ threads that do nothing but take turns wait()ing and notify()ing each other, and then you'd have to run that in some configuration that only allows it to run on _one processor_.  Even that would only be a crude approximation because wait() and notify() do more than just switch context.  It's hard to measure something that you can neither isolate nor control.

Comment: P.S., if you were implemeting your own operating system, then you would already know how to measure context switch time.  If you are _not_ implementing your own operating system then why do you care?  Not only is it _hard_ to measure what you can neither isolate nor control, it's also _pointless_.  Measure something that you _can_ control.

Comment: @MartinJames "Time it with a stopwatch. Divide the time by 50000000". This is really cool advice, I think it is part of a more general adage that simple systems can get you pretty far.